# Is this question off-topic or am I missing something?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I am referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30253662/2173917) question.

IMHO, this should be off-topic, and I voted so.

My point:

1. Question body says, `"I'm after the most efficient way to do this."`  --> Too broad
2. There is no effort visible from OP's side.
3. `However I'm not sure how to implement this` -- Does not entirely sound like a problem that is localized.

> Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.

Except the last criteria, all are *missing*.

**Q:** What should be the verdict?

*P.S. - Question (upvoted) has answer (upvoted), if that matters.*

Comment: I also voted to close as too broad, but note that your point 2 is *not* a reason to close vote. Lack of effort is only a reason to downvote (if you feel like downvoting for that reason).

Comment: @ChrisHayes And a reason to not post an answer, since otherwise you would encourage that user in his behaviour.

Comment: I think its fine.  He has a well defined problem.  He wants to do so efficiently, mentioned one way of doing so he had thought of and is asking if there is a better way.  That's not too broad, not for such a constrained question.  Its not the best question in the world, but eliminating questions like this would pretty much only leave "Help me debug my code of trivial errors" questions left.

Comment: @GabeSechan I never said the question is less worthy. I was just trying to figure out the _scope_. What about programmersSE then?

Comment: @GabeSechan the term `efficiently` itself is a broad word, it cannot have a fixed or particular solution, most of the time, there needs to be a trade-off. However, you're free to disagree sir. I respect that and much appriciate you for sharing your view. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Then you discuss the tradeoff.  But if you prefer, imagine the question without the word efficiently used.  Would that still be a valid question?  Absolutely.  So the fact that the word is in there doesn't make it off topic, except at maybe pedantics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Basically, what you're doing is bullrushing a newbie user (under 100 rep) and rather than try to help a question you want to yell at him to move it to another site (which he probably neither knows nor cares about and has a fraction of the userbase) because of wording.  Because nobody is going to think that "How do you raise a matrix to the nth power in C" is off topic.  Do you want to chase off users?  Because that's a good way to.  And I think stackoverflow is better for having the question answered.

Comment: I typically vtc these as unclear  As in, "Oh, that's your requirement? How special.  Now, what's the issue you're having while coding your solution?"  Sometimes these are shut down in a heartbeat. Sometimes they are received well. It's really the luck of the draw who sees them.